# Unable to load images in the freemarker template

Tags: freemarker, dropwizard

I am very new to using Dropwizard and the Freemarker template. I am trying to load the free marker template. However the images are not loaded in the page being displayed

i use the standard img tags of html to show the images

```
<img src="/media/images/mload.png" width="18" height="18" />
```

The images are available in the jar file.

Here is the structure of the project

src
|
 - main
    |
     --resources
        |
         --media
            |
             ---images
                |
                 ---mload.png

kindly let me know if am missing anything to display the image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the official documentation](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/core.html#bundles):

> `AssetBundle` provides a simple way to serve static assets from your service’s `src/main/resources/assets` directory as files available from `/assets/*` in your service.

You need to add the `AssetBundle` to your service with something like:

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<HelloWorldConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.setName("hello-world");
    bootstrap.addBundle(new AssetsBundle());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcello Nuccio, it helped me.

Comment: For an example Dropwizard project using Freemarker and serving assets see here: https://github.com/gary-rowe/MultiBitStore